# Unable to pass correct Uri of saved image with cameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file, android-camerax

I'm trying to send image captured and saved from CameraX to server with multipart and retrofit. But after saving the image, i'm getting      `Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`

First I clicked the image from CameraX and then, saved it to the folder created at internal storage, passed the Uri from the file to the uploadImage function.

How do I get correct uri?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ScanFragment : Fragment(), UploadRequestBody.UploadCallBack {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ScanFragment()
    }

    fun newInstance() = ScanFragment()


    private val viewModel: SocialViewModel by viewModels()
    var binding: ScanFragmentBinding by autoCleared()
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = ScanFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
        if (allPermissionGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                requireActivity(), REQUIRED_PERMISSION,
                REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION
            )
        }

        binding.btnCapture.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto()
        }

        setupObserver()

    }

    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = context?.externalMediaDirs?.firstOrNull()?.let { file ->
            File(file, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply {
                mkdirs()
            }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else requireContext().filesDir
    }

    private fun allPermissionGranted() =
        REQUIRED_PERMISSION.all {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(), it
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
            if (allPermissionGranted()) {
                //get the picture
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permissions not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                //TODO: GET BACK (FINISH())
            }
        }

    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return
        val photoFIle = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(
                FILE_NAME_FORMAT,
                Locale.getDefault()
            ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"
        )
        val outputOption = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
            photoFIle
        ).build()

        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOption, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {

                    val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFIle)
                    val msg = "Photo Saved"
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "$msg $savedUri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //TODO: SEND PHOTO AND WAIT FOR RESPONSE
                    uploadImage(savedUri)
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "$exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.e(TAG, "onError: ${exception.message}", exception)
                }

            }
        )
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProvideFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProvideFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProvideFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()
                .also { preview ->
                    preview.setSurfaceProvider(
                        binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider
                    )
                }
            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    requireActivity(), cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "startCamera Fail: ", e)
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
    }

    private fun uploadImage(savedUri: Uri) {
        //set progress bar
        binding.progressBar.progress = 0
        if (savedUri != null) {
            val parcelFileDescriptor =
                requireContext().contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(savedUri, "r", null)
                    ?: return

            val inputStream = FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
            val file = File(
                requireContext().cacheDir,
                requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(savedUri)
            )
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)

            val body = UploadRequestBody(file, "image", this)
            //TODO: SEND
            Log.d(TAG, "uploadImage: $savedUri")
///            viewModel.scanPhoto(
//                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFile", file.name, body)
//            )
        }
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(percentage: Int) {
        binding.progressBar.progress = percentage
    }
```

I'm getting the error at
val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

Comment: You already have a file for the image. You create it in `takePhoto()`, and it is called `photoFIle`. Pass that into `uploadImage()`, and use that with your `UploadRequestBody`.

Comment: @CommonsWare it says network call has failed: timeout